# Volume Exponential Function

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, volume

I should find the Volume received by rotating the region bounded by:
$y = e^x $, $ y = 0 $,$ x = 0 $, $ x = 1 $ rotated around the x axis. 
I know how to find it by using the disc method but I could not find a way to do it with the shell one.

Comment: Sketch the region. We will be integrating with respect to $y$. There is a small problem, we have to break up the interval of integration, $0$ to $1$ (though that part is a cylinder and does not require integration) and $y=1$ to $e^1$.

Comment: Yeah, I do not have problem with the interval. Actually, I could not figure out how to write the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we rotate the part from $y=0$ to $y=1$ about the $x$-axis, we get a cylinder. The volume of the cylinder can be found using cylindrical shells, but can be found more simply.

As to the part between $y=1$ and $y=e$, the radius of the cylindrical shell at height $y$ is $y$. The "height" of the cylinder is $1-x$. In terms of $y$ it is $1-\ln y$. So the volume obtained by rotating that part is 
$$\int_{y=1}^e 2\pi y(1-\ln y)\,dy.$$
Use integration by parts, $u=1-\ln y$, $dv=y\,dy$. The disk method is more pleasant!